# How to tell what week it is in Python?

Tags: python

So say I have a date, for example, 08/27/2014, and I want to find out what week it is (like if it's the first week, or the second week, or the third week. In this case, it would the fourth week), assuming that a new week starts on Sunday. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to do this?

Comment: "assuming that a new week starts on Wednesday" Strange weeks...

Comment: What are the rules for the week number when the First of January is a Saturday, Friday, Thursday, ... Sunday?  The chances are that `strftime()` can provide what you want in its Pythonesque incarnation.

Comment: As mentioned by Jonathan, `strftime` should work great with "%U" (as weeks start on Sundays for you).

Comment: If the first of January falls on a sunday, then that would be the first week of January. Otherwise, I think it would be the last week of December.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it simply using the `isocalendar` function (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar).

If your week starts on Wed instead of Mon, you just need a little logic get the correct number (-1 if you're on a Mon or Tue).

EDIT : saw you edit after posting, but still works, just need a different logic (+1 if you're on a Sunday)

Comment: Just a little logic is a bit of an understatement, I think.  But the question has been revised to a more orthodox Sunday start (though ISO 8601 weeks start on Monday).

Answer (score 0):

Week as a service:

```
import urllib2
import re

def week():
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://vecka.nu')
    html = response.read()
    match = re.search('datetime="(\d+)-W(\d+)"', html, re.M)
    if match:
        return int(match.group(2))
```

Just kidding! Although, this is how I usually check which week it is ;)